# How do I resolve this error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UTF_32BE?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am using the OWL API to read an ontology file. My code is as below:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
IRI iri = IRI.create(new File("src\\main\\webapp\\resources\\inputfile\\20171218 ontology test v0.6.owl"));
System.out.println(iri);
//I am getting error in below line
OWLOntology moduleOWL = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(iri);
```

I am getting the following exception. I have tried all the way to solve the problem, but did not succeed.

```
file:/D:/Company/Workspace/My%20Data/MyDATA/src/main/webapp/resources/inputfile/20171218%20ontology%20test%20v0.6.owl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UTF_32BE
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.wrap(DocumentSources.java:248)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.getInputStreamFromContentEncoding(DocumentSources.java:284)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.connectWithFiveRetries(DocumentSources.java:227)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.getInputStream(DocumentSources.java:150)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.wrapInput(DocumentSources.java:115)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.wrapInputAsReader(DocumentSources.java:79)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.wrapInputAsReader(DocumentSources.java:96)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.getInputSource(AbstractOWLParser.java:38)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:59)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:188)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.load(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1072)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1033)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:973)
    at com.ifour.mydata.test.ConvertXMLtoRDF.getOwlProperty(ConvertXMLtoRDF.java:402)
    at com.ifour.mydata.test.ConvertXMLtoRDF.main(ConvertXMLtoRDF.java:114)
```

Comment: it probably comes from blanks in your path. Cant remember what is the replacement character for blank but you can try to rename and remove all blanks in the path. for example "My Data" should change like "My_Data".

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mBogaz. I can't change the path as I have to use that path only, even I tried to encode the path but failed to resolve my error.

Comment: It's not the filename. The problem is an old version of Apache Commons IO on your classpath.

Comment: I'd really suggest to use a build system like Maven, Gradle etc.

Comment: I am already using the maven @AKSW

Comment: and which version(s) of Apache Commons IO do you import? `mvn dependency:tree` As other already mentioned, you have some version conflict. Don't override the version that OWL API needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem occurs because you have a version of Apache Commons IO in your classpath that is incompatible with the Owl API.**

I worked this out as follows...

I read the exception. It mentioned `UTF_32BE` not being a field and said in which class and method the problem occurred, so I dug out [the source code](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/api/src/main/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/io/DocumentSources.java) for Owl API's `DocumentSources.wrap()` method:

```
public static InputStream wrap(InputStream delegate) {
    checkNotNull(delegate, "delegate cannot be null");
    return new BOMInputStream(delegate, ByteOrderMark.UTF_8, ByteOrderMark.UTF_16BE,
        ByteOrderMark.UTF_16LE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_32BE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_32LE);
}
```

It references various `UTF_*` fields on `ByteOrderMark`, not all of which are failing. I found that `ByteOrderMark` is imported from Apache Commons IO:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderMark;
```

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/ByteOrderMark.java) for `ByteOrderMark`, it has the field defined as follows:

```
/**
 * UTF-32BE BOM (Big-Endian)
 * @since 2.2
 */
public static final ByteOrderMark UTF_32BE = new ByteOrderMark("UTF-32BE", 0x00, 0x00, 0xFE, 0xFF);
```

Which suggests that you have an earlier than 2.2 version of Apache Commons IO on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @aetheria.In my another test project it should work fine.but when I use My%Data path then its give me an error.So I think it's not the problem of Apache Commons IO.

Comment: The cause of the exception is an old version of Apache Commons IO (as you can see if you follow through my explanation). You may have problems with filenames too, but those *aren't* what's causing the exception you mentioned.

Comment: Agreed. The file name is fine. The exception appears after the file has been opened.

Comment: Thanks, @aetheria you are right its an issue of Apache Commons IO I have added Apache Commons IO 2.6 to my dependency